# Definitive fool-proof steps for 0MQ / ZeroMQ and Java on Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit, zeromq

I've been trying to use 0MQ in my Windows dev environment with Java but I'm having a very difficult experience. It appears there are many issues with PATHs being inconsistent and the Visual Studio command prompt uses a different version of Java than the command prompt where I run my application. The inconsistencies don't stop there, and I feel like I'm not approaching this correctly.

So instead of trying to patch this process, has anyone successfully used ZeroMQ on Windows 7 64-bit and what steps and software stack did you use so that you can run a Java application locally?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This sounds more like configuration than programming (might get better responses on ServerFault?)

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'm testing a new process right now and will post it over there if I don't get much farther in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used zmq with F# on Win7/64bit; it's very easy to make it work there.

As for the Java side of things, I found this documentation: http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:java
and 
https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq which is the official binding.

Comment: Interesting I wasn't familiar with F#. Unfortunately I found jzmq to have some issues with Windows architecture, so I am waiting it out. My only worry is introducing .NET to a JVM architecture. I'll report back if I have results :)